# Почему не приходят письма на почту ? ошибок не выдает

Tags: php, javascript

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="blogs__form" >
   <textarea name="messageFF" id="messageFF" required rows="5" placeholder="Детали заявки…" class="w100 border"></textarea><br>
   <input id="nameFF" type="text" name="nameFF" value="" required placeholder="имя" x-autocompletetype="name" class="w100 border"><br>
   <input id="contactFF" type="email" name="contactFF" value="" required placeholder="email" x-autocompletetype="email" class="w100 border"><br>
   <input type="file" name="fileFF[]" multiple id="fileFF" class="w100">
   <button type="submit"value="Отправить" type="submit" id="submitFF">отправить</button>
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById('blogs__form').addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
var http = new XMLHttpRequest(), f = this;
evt.preventDefault();
http.open("POST", "../contacts.php", true);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    alert(http.responseText);
  if (http.responseText.indexOf(f.nameFF.value) == 0) { // очистить поле сообщения, если в ответе первым словом будет имя отправителя
    f.messageFF.removeAttribute('value');
    f.messageFF.value='';
    }
  }
}
 http.onerror = function() {
   alert('Извините, данные не были переданы');
}
http.send(new FormData(f));
}, false);
</script>

<?php
if (isset ($_POST['contactFF'])) {
$to = "mebelnaya-obivka@mail.ru";
$from = $_POST['contactFF'];
$subject = "Заполнена контактная форма с ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$message = "Имя: ".$_POST['nameFF']."\nEmail: ".$from."\nIP: 
".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\nСообщение: ".$_POST['messageFF'];
$boundary = md5(date('r', time()));
$filesize = '';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
$message="
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"

--$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message";
 for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['fileFF']['name']);$i++) {
 if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
     $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])));
     $filename = $_FILES['fileFF']['name'][$i];
     $filetype = $_FILES['fileFF']['type'][$i];
     $filesize += $_FILES['fileFF']['size'][$i];
     $message.="

--$boundary
Content-Type: \"$filetype\"; name=\"$filename\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"

$attachment";
   }
 }
 $message.="
 --$boundary--";

if ($filesize < 10000000) { // проверка на общий размер всех файлов. Многие почтовые сервисы не принимают вложения больше 10 МБ
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   echo $_POST['nameFF'].', Ваше сообщение получено, спасибо!';
  } else {
    echo 'Извините, письмо не отправлено. Размер всех файлов превышает 10 МБ.';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `mail()` - возвращает true? без прикреплений почта отправляется?

Comment: выяснил вот что, на yandex почта приходит все норм, на mail нет, почему кто нибудь знает ?

Comment: В спам не попадают?

Comment: проверял, нету в спаме. Я думаю это связанно непосредственно с mail.ru что то у них